# icon not displaying in menu bar

Tags: icons, menu

I am using Elementary OS Freya and since I installed a program not using the included software manager, I get an icon in the menu bar like this: [image: icon]

I tried to do

```
sudo apt-get update -> Sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then I installed the packages that were held back and did

```
Sudo autoremove
```

I am a noob at this sorry..I noticed that Unity was installed too..

Comment: Are you using the default icon theme for elementary OS?  Try it and see the results.

Comment: Yes, this started happening after installing software from another source than the included software manager. I did not however install a new desktop or new icons or themes.

Comment: Are you looking to hide the icon, or to apply a different icon to it? What program did you install?

Comment: Can you please add information about that mysterious software you installed? A name, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Open task manger immediately after you login to your computer and check which application is running and does not show its icon.  For instance, Dropbox does that.  To make sure which application missing just try to treminate that application this will remove the icon from the topbar.

Answer (score 0):

Your icon-theme have'nt the application icon, look in internet the icon that's you like an put it in the folder of your icon-theme as root. Logout. Excuse my english.